# onTouchEvent get two inputs and moves player one direction like if it stuck

Tags: java

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) 
    {
        switch (state)
        {
        case Ready:
        {
            state = GameState.Running;
            break;
        }
        case GameOver:
        {
            state=GameState.Ready;
            plane.getBombs().clear();
            soldier.setAlive(true);
            break;
        }
        case Paused:
        {
            state = GameState.Running;
            break;
        }
        case Running:
        {
            if (event.getX() < screenWidth/2)
            {
                soldier.moveLeft();
                soldier.setMovingLeft(true);
            }
            else if (event.getX() > screenWidth/2 ) 
            {
                soldier.moveRight();
                soldier.setMovingRight(true);
            }
        }
            break;
        default:
            break;

        }

    }

    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) 
    {
        if (event.getX() < screenWidth/2)
        {
            soldier.stopLeft();
        }
         if (event.getX() > screenWidth/2) 
        {
            soldier.stopRight();
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

If Im holding and touching the right side with one finger player moves fine but while touch the right side and i touch left and release the player moves to the right non stop until i touch the right side

Comment: Can you show you us your `moveLeft()` and `moveRight()` methods?

Comment: public void moveRight()
 {
  speedX += moveSpeed; 
 }

 public void moveLeft() 
 {
  speedX = -moveSpeed;
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing:

```
public void moveLeft() { speedX = -moveSpeed; }
```

to:

```
public void moveLeft() { speedX -= moveSpeed; }
```

Comment: no that doesn't work to me it seems like it get two touches and it gets stuck on the first one the player moves fine and all it just when you touch the left and right side of the screen at the same time it gets stuck moving one direction

Comment: You need to add a condition to see if there is a multi touch: `if(event.getPointerCount()>1) //do something`.

Comment: Now if i do that how do i get the last fingers touch